# Cannot share screen on Zoom in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, zoom-meeting

When I try sharing screen on Zoom, I get the following error:

> can not start share, wayland has not been supported yet, please use x11 instead

- Zoom version 2.0.106600.0904
- Ubuntu  17.10

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WARNING !  Use this answer only for ubuntu 17 (see below comments)**

edit the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file and uncomment the following line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Comment: WARNING ! Don't use try this answer with ubuntu 18.04 ! i've tried this and it has completly turn down my system after reboot : unable to login in any account. I had to restore config manualy in recovery mode with root terminal

Comment: I just wasted about 30 minutes trying to get my computer beyond a black login screen because I did not consider @Fabien advise.  Make sure you know what to do if your computer boots blank before trying this option.  Ubuntu 20.  Check to make sure you know how to get into "recover mode" before using this option.

Comment: Worked on Debian 11 Bullseye by changing the file `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf`
Now `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` returns `x11` instead of `wayland` and I can share entire screen

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem with Fedora 26.  Looks like wayland is a window manager that some distros are using in lieu of X11 (Xorg).  To see what window manager you're using you can use the following:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

In Fedora, I can select the desktop environment (gnome with Xorg) at the login screen which will enable X11 instead of Wayland - looks like you can do the same with Ubuntu.

This ticket has more information if you're interested:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336219/gnome-defaults-to-wayland-how-can-i-go-to-back-to-x11

Answer (score 1):

I used this command and it worked fine for me but I think the lightdm won't be used anymore but this can probably help someone:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

If lightdm is not installed just run the `sudo apt-get install lightdm` and a screen with 2 options will popup pick lightdm and restart.

And btw this should also work:

```
sudo vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
uncomment #WaylandEnable=false
restart
```

Comment: This fixed it for me on Debian 9.9.

Answer (score 0):

I was also faced this issue. After do the following changes and restart, helped me to fix this issue.

Please check https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/336227/260822

Hope It will be helpful for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked well:

step 1: `sudo chmod 777 /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
step 2: `gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
step 3: uncommented `WaylandEnable=false`
step 4: save file and close
step 5: restart computer
setp 6: now, can share screen on skype, hangouts and zoom

My SO is ubuntu 17.10